# Is there a way to access dbutils within RStudio Server built on top of a databricks cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, sparklyr, rstudio-server

I need to access the secrets scopes defined in Databricks inside the **RStudio Server** running on a databricks cluster.

How can I access `dbutils.secrets.get` function from RStudio Server on Databricks?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `dbutils` isn't supported in RStudio, only in the Databricks notebooks.  You can raise feature request to the account executive/solution architect who works with your organization